# blinking cursor when view controller appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How to blink the cursor of a textview when the viewController appears?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

in `viewDidAppear`.

In Objective-C, that would be `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`.

Comment: Maybe the same cursor behavior, but note that the question was about a textview, not a textfield.

Answer (score 3):

You need to to put the *focus* on the textview by assigning it the first responder:

`textView.becomeFirstResponder();`

you can call this in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`